# rails - Handling Layout content_for with AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a an application layout template with:

```
<%= yield(:railed) %>
```

To handle contact in the right rail (right column 300px). In the actualy DEF SHOW page I use:

```
<%- content_for(:railed) do -%>
HTML STUFF goes here
<%- end -%>
```

The issue I'm having now is that for one of my controllers, Im using AJAX to hit DEF Show, and inject the content into the page. This work fine expect for it doesn't get the railed content as the layout template isn't being used in the format.js response.

So what's a smart way I can get the railed contet display with the AJAX request, and not have to write to separate pages for AJAX & Non-AJAX (direct URL).

Thoughts? I know some Rails genius has figured this out already :)

My controller:

```
  def show
    @thing = Thing.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.js
    end
  end
```

show.js.erb:

```
<%= render :partial =>"thing/show" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a hack but this is how I did it in rails 3.1 with haml and jquery:

show.html.haml:

```
- if request.xhr?
  #content_for_sidebar.hidden
    =@view_flow.get(:sidebar)
```

ajax_callbacks.js:

```
$("#nav a[data-remote]").live('ajax:complete', function(status, xhr) {
  $($(this).attr('rel')).html(xhr.responseText);
  $('#sidebar').html($("#content_for_sidebar").html());
  $("#content_for_sidebar").remove();
});
```